# Bootstrap modal flickers in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap modal flickers when I continuously open and close Bootstrap's modal by click on button and then pressing Esc. It works fine though in Chrome and Safari.

I changed the default style from:

```css
.modal {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

To the following:

```css
.modal {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I confirm if I change it back to scroll it works fine in Firefox too but with a ugly scrollbar. Probably the Bootstrap developers knew so they added it purposefully. Is there any way I could avoid the scrollbar and make it work in Firefox too? I am using Firefox 29.0.1

Comment: A fiddle would be really helpful.  [Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/YJTLk/), but it doesn't seem to broken in FF

Comment: @KyleMit: the popup does jump initially on the screen. I just ran your example with overflow-y: auto. I can see popup jump on the screen. Please check again. Click Launch modal popup and press Esc again click again press Esc and so on. You will surely notice the popup jump a bit on the top.